# JUnit bizarre Assertion "null" issue

Tags: java, junit

I am using the following import statement:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.fail;
```

Inside my test method:

```
public class WeirdTest {
    @Test
    public void thisIsWeird() {
        System.out.println("1");
        System.out.println("2");
        fail();
        System.out.println("3");
    }
}
```

In the console output I see:

> 1
>
> 2
>
> null

I'm not seeing "3" print!  Instead, the unit test *passes* (without printing the "3")!! What is going on here?!? I'm in Eclipse and have JUnit on my classpath (otherwise it would be giving me errors on the import statement or the `@Test` annotation). Thanks in advance.

Comment: The test runner is explicitly saying it passes?

Comment: Create a complete selfstanding example.

Comment: How are you running the test (which IDE or command-line)?

Comment: @Thorb - please see my edit for selfstanding example (all that is omitted is package and import statements, although the lone import is a part of the original question).

Comment: @Garrett - I am right-clicking my test file and selecting `Run As >> JUnit Test`.

Comment: What happens when you debug the calls step-by-step?

Comment: @herpylderp in that case, make a simple class just showing what you see, so others can copy it directly into their IDE and see the behaviour for themselves.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen What is not complete on the example given? I literally copypasted it (without the described behaviour, of course, 'cause that should work).

Comment: @Slanec If a simple "copy the whole thing - paste in IDE" is not enough to get it compiling but you need to do things, you cannot be absolutely certain that people are looking at the same thing.    Why not just create a single small class showing the behaviour you see?  Perhaps you even discover _why_ when creating the smaller version.

Comment: @Slanec Also you are asking people for help.  Anything requiring an extra effort from whoever that might perhaps help you, _will_ result in fewer responses.

Comment: @herpylderp So this is in Eclispe?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're using a version with a bug. What junit version are you using?
in version 4.4 it works well

Comment: With JUnit 4.10 it prints: "1,2" only - the same as @richarbernal

Comment: Same even with 4.0. There hasn't ever been a bug this serious. I'd say the debug mode has the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely an issue with Eclipse, or you have a fail method in the class. I ran this in IDEA and it failed, as expected. For some reason the Eclipse runner is not picking up the failure. What version of Eclipse?